Why is it undefined behavior to std::launder a multidimensional array?
I was reading the docs for std::launder and I came across this code snippet:
int x2[2][10];
auto p2 = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<int(*)[10]>(&x2[0][0]));
// Undefined behavior: x2[1] would be reachable through the resulting pointer to x2[0]
// but is not reachable from the source

What is int(*)[10] supposed to mean?
I read it as "array of ints of size 10". But then the UB comment doesn't make sense to me. x2[0] and p2 are both size 10. As long as you don't try to do arithmetic above the 10th element (eg p2+10) then you shouldn't be in UB land, right?
The closest thing I found to an answer is provided in 71631428, but it doesn't fully answer my questions.
Edit:

What is int(*)[10] supposed to mean?

I finally found the answer and it is so basic knowledge: "Pointer to an array of ints of size 10".
The other question about UB remains. So I will edit the title appropriately.

I read it as "array of ints of size 10" You are ignoring the *. Its a pointer to an array.

It seems your responded while I was editing it. Thanks for your reply.

Short answer: C++ standards require that only elements reachable through the original object’s type should be accessed.
Long Answer:
Have a look at what the memory layout of x2 may look like
x2[0][0], x2[0][1], ..., x2[0][9], x2[1][0], x2[1][1], ..., x2[1][9]

The addresses are contagious and the elements are laid in a single block of memory that you can iterate over.
This piece of code reinterpret_cast<int(*)[10]>(&x2[0][0]); tells the compiler to treat the memory at x2[0][0] as the start of an array of 10 ints however this address is nothing but a single integer inside a larger container.
But because it's C++, and you are using reinterpret_cast, you can indeed do something like this
(*p2)[11] = 2; /* this code should access x2[1][1] */
So with all that said (elements are contiguous in memory and in C++ you can do almost anything), a line like this (*p2)[11] = 2; will work but since you can't access x2[11] from the address given by the source &x2[][], this code is identified by the standards as an undefined behavior.

So the mere fact that the next array is reachable by the pointer is UB even if you don't ever try to access that array, right?

@user10260481 exactly.
